# do section in lambda notation - for mapM_ function

Tags: haskell

How to use `do` notation in lambda expression in `mapM_` ?

```
mapM_ (\x -> do let x = someComputation, return ())
```

In real, I am searching for something like this comma.

Comment: `do { let x = someComputation; return () }`? Assuming the actual code makes more sense (as shown, it will have no effect).

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much!

Comment: That should be `do let { x = someComputation }; return ()`. Otherwise `let` will try to parse `return` as the beginning of a local binding.

Answer (score 1):

A `do` block can be included, properly indented, even in a lambda-expression.  So, the following code will work fine:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = mapM_ (\x -> do let y = x * 10
                      print y
                      return ()) [1..10]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `{ ... ; ... }` alternative syntax in place of indentation for `do` and `let` blocks as noted by @Ryan and @melpomene, so this will work fine, too:

```
foo = mapM_ (\x -> do { let { y = x * 10 }; print y; return () }) [1..10]
```

You can avoid the extra `{...}` around the `let` by using the following combination of `{...}` syntax and indentation:

```
foo = mapM_ (\x -> do { let y = x * 10
                      ; print y; return () }) [1..10]
```

Here, the fact that the semicolon is in an earlier column than the `y` in the `let` line ends the `let` statement, then the semicolon separates it from the second statement in the do-block.  For details, see [Section 2.7 Layout of the Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#lexemes-layout) which describes how indentation-based layout is turned into brace notation.